# Drop FK with random numbers at the end

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

In my Database one FK has weird random numbers at the end. It seems that on each server it has different value so I can't drop it correctly...
How to drop FK without knowing numbers?

```
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.foreign_keys WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].
[FK__PRData__PRCon__75EFBF14]') AND parent_object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[PRData]'))
```

Comment: You can query `sys.foreign_keys` to find out its name.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `LIKE` keyword, and if you use a percent sign for the wildcard, you can then select the FK if it exists, then delete that row, or do whatever you want.

You can look at this for more help:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/98434

```
SELECT object_id FROM sys.foreign_keys WHERE object_id LIKE
OBJECT_ID(N'FK__PRData__PRCon__75EFBF14%') AND 
parent_object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[PRData]')
```